# Git prepare-commit-msg hook does not get any arguments

Tags: bash, git, hook, githooks, git-commit

I want to create custom `prepare-commit-msg` hook for my git repository.
Firstly I read about arguments, so I created something like test to see values of those arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly file_with_message=$1
readonly source_of_message=$2
readonly commit_sha=$3

echo "File: \"${file_with_message}\""
echo ""
echo "Source: \"${source_of_message}\""
echo ""
echo "SHA: \"${commit_sha}\""
echo ""
```

And I got following log:

```
File: ""

Source: ""

SHA: ""

commit-msg File: ""
[1111-pre-commit-msg-test 4f347d4] add .idea
5 files changed, 189 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 .idea/fast.iml
create mode 100644 .idea/misc.xml
create mode 100644 .idea/modules.xml
create mode 100644 .idea/vcs.xml
create mode 100644 .idea/workspace.xml
```

Basically, I can see, that my hook is being executed during the commit, but there are no arguments. There should be at least the first one.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
```

Does anyone know, why it happened?
Thx :)

PS: I can see the same behaviour for `commit-msg` hook. (there is also one log msg from that)

Comment: Yes, there should indeed be at least the one argument. Try having the hook exit with status 1 to prevent the commit, so that you can be sure that *that particular* hook is the one executing?

Comment: It is:
`cermado1:fast admin$ git commit -m "add .idea"`
`File: ""`

`Source: ""`

`SHA: ""`

`cermado1:fast admin$ echo $?`
`1`

Comment: And commit was aborted.

Comment: Hey, I just realised. I know what happened. I will make a separate comment.

Answer (score 3):

The reason was, that we had custom system of hooks execution:

Every `<hook>` tried to execute `<hook>.local` and `<hook>.enectiva` (enectiva is our product, that's why the extension)

So in this case:

File `prepare-commit-msg` hook contained:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hook_name="prepare-commit-msg"
git_path=".git/hooks"
files="./${git_path}/${hook_name}.local ./${git_path}/${hook_name}.enectiva"

for f in ${files}; do
    if [[ -f ${f} ]]; then
        ${f} || exit 1
    fi
done
```

This file also got the right arguments, but did not pass them on.
My previous log code was from `prepare-commit-msg.enectiva`, so it was a bit misleading. And `prepare-commit-msg.enectiva` did not receive any arguments.

So the resolution is to use `${f} $1 $2 $3`

This is the result after changing the hook:

```
File: ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"

Source: "message"

SHA: ""
```

**EDIT:**

```
 ${f} "${@}" || exit 1
```

Comment: *So the resolution is to use `${f} $1 $2 $3`*  —that's not quite right; the script should invoke `${f} "$@"`, which automatically provides *all* arguments, or *no* arguments, correctly, regardless of what's in the actual arguments. (Note that for filters that receive input on stdin, the problem is harder: this script is sufficient for filters that recieve only arguments.)